# Angular JS - Dynamic values sum based on Radio Button selection

Tags: angularjs

In view there are two lists of radio buttons

L1

```
<input type="radio" name="SET1" ng-model="SET1Selected" value="1"> 1
<input type="radio" name="SET1" ng-model="SET1Selected" value="2"> 2
<input type="radio" name="SET1" ng-model="SET1Selected" value="3"> 3
```

L2

```
<input type="radio" name="SET2" ng-model="SET2Selected" values="4"> 4
<input type="radio" name="SET2" ng-model="SET2Selected" value="5"> 5
<input type="radio" name="SET2" ng-model="SET2Selected" value="6"> 6

<div> {{value of radio button selected from L1}}+{{value of radio button selected from L2}}</div>
```

Sum will change depending on selections from L1 and L2

Comment: @Sajeetharan . Kindly look into my next query.:)

Answer (score 1):

You can do with the expression,

```
<div> {{parseInt(SET1Selected)+parseInt(SET2Selected) }}</div>
```

**DEMO**

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
 app.controller("myCtrl", ['$scope', function($scope) {
$scope.parseInt = parseInt;

 }]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.7/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <div class="row">
  <input type="radio" name="SET1" value="1" ng-model="SET1Selected" > 1
  <input type="radio" name="SET1" value="2" ng-model="SET1Selected"  > 2
  <input type="radio" name="SET1" value="3" ng-model="SET1Selected" > 3
  </div>
  <div class="row">
  <input type="radio" name="SET2" value="4" ng-model="SET2Selected" > 4
  <input type="radio" name="SET2" value="5" ng-model="SET2Selected" > 5
  <input type="radio" name="SET2" value="6" ng-model="SET2Selected" > 6
  </div>
  <div class="row">
  <div> {{parseInt(SET1Selected)+parseInt(SET2Selected) }}</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What if I dont hv value directly available in value="4". My value will be a key of object over which I'll iterate to make radio buttons  and a different key is present in value say value="XYZ".

Comment: still you are going to bind a variable, so it will be the same

Comment: L1=[{a:1,b:2},{a:4,b:5}]..L2=[{a:7,b:6},{a:8,b:9}] ... Using ng-repeat over this i created radio buttons with a as value="" ,Now if want (L1.b + L2.b )depending on object chosen from L1 and L2.

Comment: what are these?

Comment: L1 L2.  i have 2 datasets from which i'll create list of radio buttons

Answer (score 0):

Small tips as below you can use it

```
{{(SET1Selected - 0) + (SET2Selected - 0)}}
```

Or

```
{{(SET1Selected*1) + (SET2Selected*1)}}
```

Demo:

https://codeide.co/wCudpQka